# How to do least squares fitting with matrix product of 3 matrices?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I want to optimize a function $E = \sum_i(Y_i-f(Z_i))^2$ w.r.t. $T$ where $f(Z)=ZTV^t$, and all are matrices (not necessarily square). Here $T$ acts as weights as in regression for example. $Y \in R^{n \times p}$, $Z \in R^{n \times k}$, $T \in R^{k \times k}$, and $V \in R^{p \times k}$. $p,n,k$ are arbitrary integers ( $>1$).

How can I do this?

From a gradient based algorithm point of view, do you need to compute the $\partial E/\partial T_{a,b}$ where $T_{a,b}$ is an element of $T$? If so, how can you do that and after computing, do you just simultaneously perform $T_{a,b} = T_{a,b} - \alpha * \partial E/\partial T_{a,b} $ for all $a,b$ and learning rate $\alpha$ as in the usual gradient descent?

($A^t$ denotes the transpose of matrix $A$)

Comment: You can represent matrix multiplication with Kronecker products. Then it becomes a normal least squares problem in the vectorization you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
and let's define the additional matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
\def\L{\left}
\def\R{\right}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
F &= ZTV^T &\qiq dF = Z\,dT\,V^T \\
M &= \L(F-Y\R) &\qiq dM = dF \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of these new variables, then find its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
 {\mathcal E} &= M:M \\\\
d{\mathcal E} &= 2M:dM \\&=  2M:Z\,dT\,V^T \\
  &= 2Z^TMV:dT \\
\\
\frac{\partial{\mathcal E}}{\partial T}
 &= 2Z^TMV \\
 &=  2Z^T \L(F-Y\R) V \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve
$$\eqalign{
Z^TYV &= Z^TFV = Z^T \L(ZTV^T\R) V \\
\\
T &= \L(Z^TZ\R)^{-1} \L(Z^TYV\R) \L(V^TV\R)^{-1} \\
  &= Z^+Y\L(V^+\R)^T \\
}$$
where $M^+$ denotes the pseudoinverse of $M$.