# Least square of matrix products $\|A-BXC\|_F^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

Given matrices $A \in \Bbb R^{m \times q}$, $B \in \Bbb R^{m\times n}$, $C \in \Bbb R^{p\times q}$,

$$ \min_{X \in \Bbb R^{n \times p}} \, \| A - B X C \|_F^2 $$

Similar questions have been answered

- [Minimize $ \|A-BXC \|_F$ subject to $\mbox{rank} (X) \leq r$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/100758)
- [How to do least squares fitting with matrix product of 3 matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2717050)

but I think the high score answers are problematic. In particular, they claim that the solution is

$$ X=(B^TB)^{-1}B^TAC^T(CC^T)^{-1}.$$

However, it's unclear that $(B^TB)^{-1}$ and $(CC^T)^{-1}$ exist. In this case, $X$ may not be unique. To force a unique solution, maybe a regularized form is required $$\|A-BXC\|_F^2+\lambda \|X\|_F^2.$$ Are these understandings correct?

By first-order condition, the diffential of the regularized form is $$B^TBXCC^T+\lambda X=B^TAC,$$ but I'm not sure how to merge terms at this points.

Comment: Why don't you use the definition of the Frobenius norm, expand and then differentiate?

Comment: I think you've misread the answers in the linked posts. They don't use $(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$ instead they employ the pseudoinverse $B^+$ (which exists for any matrix) to obtain $$X = B^+AC^+\;$$

Comment: @greg In their answer $B^+ = (B^TB)^{-1}B^T$ but this is only true when B has independent columns. I believe they directly use the existence of this particular pseudo inverse. I think my equation is called Sylvester Matrix Equation and there's a canonical way to solve it.